# Seeking Green space layer for California

Tags: usa, research, openstreetmap

I'm looking for a data layer that can be used to display "green" spaces, which would ideally include parks (city, county, state, national), as well as golf courses and cemeteries.

Is there a single data repository that would contain all of these features?

I only need it for the state of California. I have found several government sites, but have not had too much luck so far. I'd rather not patch together dozens of layers from different sources if possible.

Comment: If you're looking for open data, the [opendata.se] is probably your best resource.

Answer (score 4):

[Openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/33.9058/-117.4301) (OSM) is an excellent source of all kinds of vector data on human infrastructure, particularly in urban areas of the USA and Europe.

[image]

You'll need to figure out which [OSM tags for polygons](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) refer to the types of green spaces you are interested in.

There are many ways to access OSM data - wholesale country downloads, regions, by tag, etc. Have a look at the [OSM wiki on data downloading](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data).

The [OSMDownloader](https://github.com/lcoandrade/OSMDownloader) plugin in QGIS will let you download rectangular areas and helpfully adds a set of symbols, including a 'natural' category:

[image]

Caution! Certainly where I live in Africa we have to be very careful about *national park and reserve boundaries* in OSM data - they often do not reflect the official boundaries, often with huge errors in both area, position or topology with neighbouring areas.

Comment: OSM has the same issue in the US - park boundaries are not always the same as official ones.